# Activate / deactivate views in WPF app using MefBootstrapper throws exception when setting the RegionName in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mef

I am looking at the PrismLibrary's WPF samples specifically to https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Samples-Wpf/tree/master/6-ViewActivationDeactivation. My goal is to create a working version of the ViewActivationDeactivation solution but using the MefBootstrapper instead the UnityBoostrapper that is originally used in the example.

I have configured my bootstrapper class like this

```
public class Bootstrapper : MefBootstrapper
{
    protected override void ConfigureAggregateCatalog()
    {
        AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(Bootstrapper).Assembly));
        base.ConfigureAggregateCatalog();
    }
    protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
    {
        return Container.GetExportedValue<MainWindow>();
    }

    protected override void InitializeShell()
    {
        Application.Current.MainWindow = (MainWindow)Shell;
        Application.Current.MainWindow.Show();
    }

    protected override CompositionContainer CreateContainer()
    {
        var container = base.CreateContainer();
        container.ComposeExportedValue(container);
        return container;
    }
}
```

and the MainWindow's code looks like this:

xaml

```
<Window x:Class="DuoApp_ViewNav.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DuoApp_ViewNav"
        xmlns:v="clr-namespace:DuoApp_ViewNav.Views"
             xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
        <ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="ContentRegion" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

xaml.cs

```
[Export]
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private CompositionContainer _container;
    private IRegionManager _regionManager;
    IRegion _region;

    ViewA _viewA;
    ViewB _viewB;

    [ImportingConstructor]
    public MainWindow(CompositionContainer container, IRegionManager regionManager)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _container = container;
        _regionManager = regionManager;

        this.Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
    }

    private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _viewA = _container.GetExportedValue<ViewA>();
        _viewB = _container.GetExportedValue<ViewB>();

        _region = _regionManager.Regions["ContentRegion"];

        _region.Add(_viewA);
        _region.Add(_viewB);
    }
}
```

The problem I am facing is that the MainWindow fails to initialize, It throws a System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException when trying to set the RegionName within the ContentControl
The inner exception message is

> Activation error occurred while trying to get instance of type
>   DelayedRegionCreationBehavior, key ""

Here the exception full details

> System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException occurred
>   HResult=-2146233087   LineNumber=12   LinePosition=10   Message='Set
>   property 'Prism.Regions.RegionManager.RegionName' threw an exception.'
>   Line number '12' and line position '10'.
>   Source=PresentationFramework   StackTrace:
>          at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean
>   skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings
>   settings, Uri baseUri)
>          at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(XamlReader xamlReader, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject,
>   XamlAccessLevel accessLevel, Uri baseUri)
>          at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(Stream stream, ParserContext parserContext, Object parent, Boolean closeStream)
>          at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator)
>          at DuoApp_ViewNav.MainWindow.InitializeComponent() in C:\Users\ralfaro\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\DuoApp_ViewNav\DuoApp_ViewNav\MainWindow.xaml:line 1
>   InnerException: 
>          HResult=-2146233088
>          Message=Activation error occurred while trying to get instance of type DelayedRegionCreationBehavior, key ""
>          Source=Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation
>          StackTrace:
>               at Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocatorImplBase.GetInstance(Type
>   serviceType, String key) in
>   c:\Projects\CommonServiceLocator\main\Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation\ServiceLocatorImplBase.cs:line
>   53
>               at Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocatorImplBase.GetInstanceTService
>   in
>   c:\Projects\CommonServiceLocator\main\Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation\ServiceLocatorImplBase.cs:line
>   90
>               at Prism.Regions.RegionManager.CreateRegion(DependencyObject element)
>               at Prism.Regions.RegionManager.OnSetRegionNameCallback(DependencyObject
>   element, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
>               at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs
>   e)
>               at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs
>   e)
>               at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs
>   args)
>               at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex
>   entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata,
>   EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean
>   coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue,
>   OperationType operationType)
>               at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(DependencyProperty dp,
>   Object value, PropertyMetadata metadata, Boolean
>   coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue,
>   OperationType operationType, Boolean isInternal)
>               at System.Windows.Baml2006.WpfMemberInvoker.SetValue(Object instance,
>   Object value)
>               at MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.SetValue(XamlMember member,
>   Object obj, Object value)
>               at MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.SetValue(Object inst,
>   XamlMember property, Object value)
>          InnerException: 
>               HResult=-2146233088
>               Message=Activation error occurred while trying to get instance of type DelayedRegionCreationBehavior, key ""
>               Source=Microsoft.Practices.Prism.MefExtensions
>               StackTrace:
>                    at Microsoft.Practices.Prism.MefExtensions.MefServiceLocatorAdapter.DoGetInstance(Type
>   serviceType, String key)
>                    at Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocatorImplBase.GetInstance(Type
>   serviceType, String key) in
>   c:\Projects\CommonServiceLocator\main\Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation\ServiceLocatorImplBase.cs:line
>   49
>               InnerException:

Honestly I have no idea why this exception is thrown. Am I missing something to make this work with the MefBootstrapper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured it out. I mistakenly referenced two assemblies that have MefBootstrapper implementations, Prism.Mef and Prism.MefExtensions. After removing the Prism.MefExtensions package/reference the application started to work fine.
My last troubleshooting step, which I found very useful and informative, was to run the Prism library code locally and add the required references from there, that allowed me to recognize that the MefExtensions were not needed.

The current version of my packages.config file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="CommonServiceLocator" version="1.3" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Prism.Core" version="6.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Prism.Mef" version="6.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Prism.Wpf" version="6.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
</packages>
```

I hope this helps someone else.